# Update/Edit already added name in the dropdown(Select)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one dropdown, how can I edit the name and update it in the dropdown, like if I want to change the text of `ABC` to `AAA` how can I achieve this ? 
There will be a new popup when edit button is clicked and user defined name  can be entered (`AAA` is just an example) which will replace the `ABC`

```
<SELECT NAME="CB" id="CBid" class ="CBclass" >
    <option value="ABC" >ABC</option>
    <option value="MCD" >MCD</option>
    <option value="XYZ" >XYZ</option>
</SELECT>
<INPUT id="Edit" TYPE="button" VALUE="Edit" onClick="EditName()" />
```

Comment: Does the value attribute need to change as well?

Comment: Yes that will change too. As I am passing the value to the other functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a possible solution:

```js
$('#Edit').on('click', function(){
  
  $('#CBid').find('option[value="ABC"]').text('AAA');
  
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<SELECT NAME="CB" id="CBid" class ="CBclass" >
    <option value="ABC" >ABC</option>
    <option value="MCD" >MCD</option>
    <option value="XYZ" >XYZ</option>
</SELECT>
<INPUT id="Edit" TYPE="button" VALUE="Edit" />
```

I hope the above code will give you an idea.

EDIT:

Here is the updated answer: https://jsfiddle.net/99x50s2s/44/

Comment: yes it did, though I actually want the user to add whatever name he wants so there will be a popup in which he can enter a new name and then hit update. then new name will be added in the dropdown

Comment: I think this should be a new question :)

Comment: I already updated my question, I was expecting that result only. Thank you @Vimalan

Comment: I see a minor conflict between your updated question and the previous comment. Do you want to edit the existing option text or add a new option into the select control?

Comment: the new user defined name will replace the existing option.

Comment: See the EDIT section fiddler in my answer. As you have not mentioned which modal window, I've used bootstrap. I hope this updated answer will give you an idea.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79066/discussion-between-psdebugger-and-vimalan-jaya-ganesh).